# How can I access my SQLite database safely with AsyncTasks?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I have a SQLite database in my application. I access it using a SQLiteOpenHelper with a static factory, so that only one helper instance exists at a time. I'm not entirely sure why this is necessary; I did it because I read there was some opportunity for leaks if multiple helpers were created:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static DatabaseHelper sInstance = null;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "score_database.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String SCORE_TABLE_NAME = "testTable";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "scorekey";
public static final String SCORE_NAME = "score";

private static final String SCORE_TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + SCORE_TABLE_NAME + " (" + KEY_NAME + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + SCORE_NAME + " INTEGER);";

/**
 * Constructor for DatabaseHelper class.
 * @param context
 */
private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

/**
 * Gets the database helper instance (if an instance already exists, it will be retrieved).
 * @param context The calling context
 * @return The database helper instance
 */
public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    if(sInstance==null)
        sInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    return sInstance;
}

/**
 * Creates the necessary database structure for score storage.
 * @param db The database object
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(SCORE_TABLE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
}
```

I have to access it without locking up the UI thread; as such, I only call getWritableDatabase from inside an AsyncTask. When the access is complete, I close the database that getWritableDatabase returned.

Now, sometimes, my app will start another AsyncTask of the same type, to perform another database access, while one is already running. I can't access the database at the same time in multiple threads, so I have a lock object shared by all the AsyncTask objects that queues up the database operations (this works fine). The problem is, once in a blue moon, the following occurs:

1. The app starts an AsyncTask that locks the database and starts accessing it.
2. The user quits the app (the task keeps running in the background; even if I cancel it, there's no stopping it if I am in the middle of a database access).
3. The user opens the app again and starts another AsyncTask. Because the lock was a field in the activity, this new AsyncTask acquires the lock in the new activity instance, and accesses the database while the old task is still running. Then an error occurs when one of the tasks closes the database while the other is trying to work with it.

The behavior is intermittent, but only because of the low chance that these conditions will be met. I don't want this to occur for a user, ever. Basically, I either need a way to let multiple tasks access the database simultaneously (eliminating the need for a lock) or a way to have a lock carry across multiple activity instances as the app is destroyed and recreated.

Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, I'd rely on Android OS as much as possible. That said, why won't you use Content Provider for DB operations? It somewhat handles multithreading/transactions/locking DB for you.
As alternative (and this solution is not smell pretty well) you can back up your lock field in SharedPreferences, as this is stored in a file, it will preserve it over application's death and rebirth, just restore it onCreate.

Comment: Content Provider was where I was leaning. I have decided (in this particular case) that the DB is overkill and I will just be using SharedPreferences for the data, but I'll remember this answer.

Answer (score 1):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` is modeled so that it caches the SQLite connection for reusing. There is no need to ever manually close the connection in this case, although the helper will automatically reopen a new connection on the next access, so if the access is kept serialized it will still work.

In my experience, SQLite transactions are serialized by the framework, so if you use the above model, then you don't need to serialize them yourself.

Also, to comment on your serialization scheme, you should have kept the shared lock static at the same level as the `AsyncTask`s (preferably using the `SQLiteOpenHelper` object itself as the lock). Also you can specify a serial executer in the `executeOnExecutor()` method, which was the default pre-Donut and was again reverted to be the the default post-Honeycomb.